# Cookies Store Bug

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm try to put in my content but cannot be display. When I refresh will display different things... Anyones can help me to slove of this problem?

```
<script src="./angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('cookieStoreExample', ['ngCookies'])
    .controller('ExampleController',['$scope', '$cookieStore', function($scope, $cookieStore){

        var exprs = $scope.exprs = [$cookieStore.get('myExprs',$scope.exprs)];

        $scope.addExp = function(exprs) {
            exprs.push(exprs);
        };


        $scope.removeExp = function(index) {
            exprs.splice(index, 1);
        };


        $cookieStore.put('myExprs',$scope.exprs);   
        var favoriteCookie = $cookieStore.get('myExprs',$scope.exprs);

    }])

</script>
```

Comment: `$scope.addExp = function(exprs) {` you have a logic problem here and on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a couple of issues with this example:

- `$cookieStore.get()` already returns a array, no need for the []'s.
- argument to `addExp()` was `exprs`, shadowing the `exprs` array.
- `$cookieStore.put()` needs to be called to persist changes.

Updated code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('cookieStoreExample', ['ngCookies'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {

        var exprs = $scope.exprs = $cookieStore.get('myExprs');
        if (!angular.isArray(exprs)) {
            exprs = [];
        }

        $scope.addExp = function (expr) {
            exprs.push(expr);
            $cookieStore.put('myExprs', exprs);
        };


        $scope.removeExp = function (index) {
            exprs.splice(index, 1);
            $cookieStore.put('myExprs', exprs);
        };


        $scope.favoriteCookie = $cookieStore.get('myExprs');

    }])

</script>
```